# Turing Machine that halts iff the tape contains at least two '1's

Tags: turing-machines

> Contruct a Turing Machine that halts if and only if the tape it is on contains at least two '1's.

My attempt:

The gist of this turing machine is that it has to check all of the cells, and since it is infinite in both directions, one way of indexing it is a follows

[image: Turing indexing]

Thus it has occurred to me to write a pseudocode for the TM's behaviour like this:

```
n:= 0           //number of '1's encountered
i:= 0           //index
while(true)
{
  if(n==2)
    halt
  for k=0 upto i
  {
    check()
    if(i even)
      move left
    if(i odd)
      move right
  }
  i++
}
```

Where check is the function defined as follows:

```
check()
{
if(current cell contains 1)
  n++
}
```

But this seems really hard to implement as a turing machine, especially since there are two variables involved. My guess is that I am overthinking and there is a much cleaner, nicer and elegant solution.

So my question is: What would be a better solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it in the end.
If anyone is interested, I left a diagram of the TM here
[image: Turing Machine]